How to change Contact form7 redirection dynamically
I am building a website for a real estate company. They want a functionality that triggers a popup when someone clicks the "Download Brochure" button. After submitting an inquiry through the popup form, the user should be automatically redirected to the brochure URL.
The website has over 1000 properties listed, and the brochure URLs are stored in ACF (Advanced Custom Fields). I am using Contact Form 7 in my popup.
How do I redirect the user to the brochure URL upon form submission?
Is there any way I can set the redirection URL based on the input from ACF?

In your question, you did not mention the post type. So, I am using the properties_list custom post type as an example, you can change it while using the given code.
Remember the wpcf7mailsent JavaScript event in Contact Form 7 is triggered when a form is successfully submitted. You can use this event to redirect after a form submission.
Follow these steps:

Create the Javascript file in child theme, ex: js/brochure.js
and add the following function in the child theme's functions.php file.
function child_enqueue_styles() {
  if(is_singular( 'properties_list' )){
    $acf_data = get_field('brochre_url', get_the_ID()); 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'brochure-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/brochure.js', '', '0.7', true );
    wp_localize_script('brochure-js', 'acfData', array(
        'brochre_url' => $acf_data
    ));
  }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );




Note: change the brochre_url in $acf_data = get_field('brochre_url', get_the_ID()); with you custom field key created in ACF.

Add the following code in brochure.js, created in the child theme js/brochure.js
document.addEventListener('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    var formId = event.detail.contactFormId;
    if (formId == 123) { // Change 123 to your actual form ID
        setTimeout( () => {
            location = acfData.brochre_url;
        }, 1000 );
    }
}, false);



Note: Change the form id (123) with the form id created in contact form 7
The code tested and worked
