How to add Dynamic Value from ACF in Contact Form7?
I am building a real estate website with over 1,000 properties. On the property view page, there is a "Download Brochure" button that triggers a popup with a Contact Form 7 form. Once someone submits the inquiry, I want them to be redirected to the brochure URL.
The "Download Brochure" button link is created with an ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) value and stored in a variable in my template.
I am using the Contact Form 7 – Dynamic Text Extension and the Redirection for Contact Form 7 Plugin.
How can I get the value of the brochure URL in Contact Form 7 and redirect the user to that dynamic value?

Is it not helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78561133/how-to-change-contact-form7-redirection-dynamically/78561935#78561935

I believe there is a way to do it right from the shortcode. Check out this page in the documentation: https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-shortcode-attributes/
